# What is the System.TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime equivalent in NodaTime?

Tags: datetime, timezone, dst, nodatime

System.TimeZoneInfo has a method called [IsDaylightSavingTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460642%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which takes a DateTime object and returns true if the specified datetime falls in the DST for that timezone. Is there an equivalent function in [NodaTime](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) or another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: I've now added a feature request to include this in ZonedDateTime directly: https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/issues/detail?id=264

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get this from a `ZoneInterval`.  Here is an extension method that will help.

```cs
public static bool IsDaylightSavingsTime(this ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime)
{
    var instant = zonedDateTime.ToInstant();
    var zoneInterval = zonedDateTime.Zone.GetZoneInterval(instant);
    return zoneInterval.Savings != Offset.Zero;
}
```

Now you can do:

```cs
zdt.IsDaylightSavingsTime();
```

If you don't have a `ZonedDateTime`, you can get one from a `DateTimeZone` plus either an  `Instant` or a `LocalDateTime`.  Or you can massage this extension method to take those as parameters.

**Update:**  This function is now included in Noda Time v1.3 and higher, so you no longer have to write the extension method yourself.