# Timezone conversion issue

Tags: c#, timezone

I am working on a program that uses UTC dates, and needs to convert to local times in certain instances. I wrote a larger program to test boundary conditions, and seem to have a problem when I convert "11/2/2014 02:00 EST" to the Mountain Time Zone.

I chopped everything out of the test program to create a sample here that contains the bare minimum to demonstrate the issue. This is a VS2010 .Net 3.5 Console Application.

```
using System.Text;

namespace DSTDebug
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // get the system EST and MST time zone info structures
            TimeZoneInfo tzEastern = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
            TimeZoneInfo tzMountain = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time");
            // create a time, 11/2/2014 02:00 EST
            // using DateTimeOffset, it should not be an ambiguous time
            // converting to Mountain Standard Time should not be ambiguous either but it's showing up that way
            // 11/2/2014 02:00 EST should be 11/2/2014 01:00 MDT
            DateTimeOffset dateToTest = new DateTimeOffset(2014, 11, 2, 2, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(tzEastern.BaseUtcOffset.Hours));
            DateTime sampleTimeUTC = dateToTest.UtcDateTime;
            ShowConversion(sampleTimeUTC, tzMountain, tzEastern);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        }

        private static void ShowConversion(DateTime sampleTimeUTC, TimeZoneInfo tzInfoM, TimeZoneInfo tzInfoE)
        {
            DateTime sampleTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sampleTimeUTC, tzInfoE);
            DateTime convertedTimeM = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sampleTimeUTC, tzInfoM);
            // write the output: {0} is sampleTime; {1} is "*" if sampleTime is DST; {2} is convertedTimeM; {3} is "*" if convertedTimeM is DST
            Console.WriteLine(" {0:MM/dd/yy HH:mm}{1}  => {2:MM/dd/yy HH:mm}{3}", sampleTime, tzInfoE.IsDaylightSavingTime(sampleTime) ? "*" : " ",
                convertedTimeM, tzInfoM.IsDaylightSavingTime(convertedTimeM) ? "*" : " ");
            // information: display if the sample time or converted time is ambiguous
            Console.WriteLine("    Sample time is{0} ambiguous", tzInfoE.IsAmbiguousTime(sampleTimeUTC) ? string.Empty : " not");
            Console.WriteLine(" Converted time is{0} ambiguous", tzInfoM.IsAmbiguousTime(convertedTimeM) ? string.Empty : " not");
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to know if I have a coding error, or if there's a boundary condition bug in .Net.
Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking why `tzInfoM.IsAmbiguousTime(convertedTimeM)` returns true?

Daylight Saving Time ends on 11/2/2014, so a `DateTime` value of 11/2/2014 1:00 AM is ambiguous in the Mountain Time Zone; it could be interpreted as either Mountain Daylight Time or Mountain Standard Time.

Indeed, if you convert `convertedTimeM` back to UTC using `tzInfoM`, you get a different time than you started with because [`ConvertTimeToUtc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495915%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) assumes that an ambiguous time is in standard time:

```
// sampleTimeUTC = 11/2/2014 7:00 AM UTC
DateTime convertedTimeM = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sampleTimeUTC, tzInfoM);
// convertedTimeM = 11/2/2014 1:00 AM
DateTime convertedTimeUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(convertedTimeM, tzInfoM);
// convertedTimeUTC = 11/2/2014 8:00 AM UTC
```

So .NET is working as expected . . . but that doesn't necessarily mean *your* code has a bug either. What are you trying to do?

**UPDATE:** Using NodaTime is a good choice. For completeness' sake, here's how to do it with the BCL types:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TimeZoneInfo tzEastern = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
    TimeZoneInfo tzMountain = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time");

    // 11/2/2014 02:00 EST should be 11/2/2014 01:00 MDT
    DateTimeOffset dateToTest;
    dateToTest = new DateTimeOffset(2014, 11, 2, 2, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(-5));
    ShowConversion(dateToTest, tzEastern, tzMountain);
    // 11/2/2014 03:00 EST should be 11/2/2014 01:00 MST
    dateToTest = new DateTimeOffset(2014, 11, 2, 3, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(-5));
    ShowConversion(dateToTest, tzEastern, tzMountain);
}

private static void ShowConversion(DateTimeOffset dateToTest, TimeZoneInfo tzEastern, TimeZoneInfo tzMountain)
{
    DateTimeOffset convertedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateToTest, tzMountain);
    Console.WriteLine("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm} {1} => {2:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm} {3}",
        dateToTest, tzEastern.IsDaylightSavingTime(dateToTest) ? "EDT" : "EST",
        convertedTime, tzMountain.IsDaylightSavingTime(convertedTime) ? "MDT" : "MST");
}
```

Comment: Michael, I ran the full set of numbers for Arizona (no DST there) over the spring-forward and fall-back, and there were no ambiguities. Same with Mountain Time, except in this one instance. I need unambiguous answers so I can display the right timezone for converted values. Somewhere I read that if you start with UTC times, conversion should never be ambiguous. If I find the link or more info, I'll add another comment.
I ran 11/2/2014 01:00 EDT through and got 23:00 MDT. I ran 11/2/2014 01:00 EST and got 00:00 MDT. Those are correct, with no ambiguities.

Comment: The conversion **from** UTC to Mountain Time is perfectly unambiguous; 1:00 AM is the correct converted time. What `IsAmbiguousTime` tells you is that the conversion from 1:00 AM **back** to UTC (or to another time zone) would be ambiguous, because `convertedTimeM` doesn't contain any information about whether it's in MDT or MST. If you need that information, then use the methods of `TimeZoneInfo` that accept and return `DateTimeOffset` values rather than `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on using Microsoft objects for this. In my research I read about Nodatime, and decided to give it a try. What I came up with works correctly on the first shot.
There are probably lots of places where it could be cleaner, but perhaps this can help someone.

```
using System;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.TimeZones;

namespace NodaDSTDebug
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IDateTimeZoneProvider timeZoneProvider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl;
            // get the system EST and MST time zone info structures
            DateTimeZone tzEastern = timeZoneProvider["Eastern Standard Time"];
            DateTimeZone tzMountain = timeZoneProvider["Mountain Standard Time"];

            // 11/2/2014 02:00 EST should be 11/2/2014 01:00 MDT
            ZonedDateTime dateToTest;
            dateToTest = new ZonedDateTime(new LocalDateTime(2014, 11, 2, 2, 0, 0), tzEastern, Offset.FromHours(-5));
            ShowConversion(dateToTest, tzMountain);
            // 11/2/2014 03:00 EST should be 11/2/2014 01:00 MST
            dateToTest = new ZonedDateTime(new LocalDateTime(2014, 11, 2, 3, 0, 0), tzEastern, Offset.FromHours(-5));
            ShowConversion(dateToTest, tzMountain);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert Eastern Time into Mountain Time
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dateToTest">Eastern Time</param>
        /// <param name="tzMountain">Mountain TimeZone</param>
        private static void ShowConversion(ZonedDateTime dateToTest, DateTimeZone tzMountain)
        {
            ZonedDateTime convertedTime = dateToTest.WithZone(tzMountain);
            // for some reason the 'x' format pattern is not working, so they are ginned up as constants
            // 'x' is printing the full timezone name e.g. "Eastern Standard Time"
            Console.WriteLine("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm x} {1} =>  {2:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm x} {3}",
                dateToTest, IsDaylightSavingsTime(dateToTest) ? "EDT" : "EST",
                convertedTime, IsDaylightSavingsTime(convertedTime) ? "MDT" : "MST");
        }

        // From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211052/what-is-the-system-timezoneinfo-isdaylightsavingtime-equivalent-in-nodatime
        // Thanks to Matt Johnson
        public static bool IsDaylightSavingsTime(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime)
        {
            Instant instant = zonedDateTime.ToInstant();
            ZoneInterval zoneInterval = zonedDateTime.Zone.GetZoneInterval(instant);
            return zoneInterval.Savings != Offset.Zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Output of program:

```
11/02/2014 02:00 EST =>  11/02/2014 01:00 MDT
11/02/2014 03:00 EST =>  11/02/2014 01:00 MST
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: This is merely a project to test boundary conditions. My current project is to convert the current time to a 'generated' time zone, using an offset from the local time zone, and a DST flag. This is for sending the current time to remote devices. Does Nodatime have the equivalent of MS's TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone()?

Comment: I'm very happy you chose to use Noda Time.  It's *much* more reliable.  You may also want to consider using the `Tzdb` provider, in which case your IDs change to "America/New_York" (for Eastern Time) or "America/Phoenix" (for Arizona) or "America/Denver" (for the rest of Mountain Time).

Comment: You might also consider creating the `LocalDateTime` first, then using one of the `.InZone...` methods to get your `ZonedDateTime`.  That will remove the need to pass a -5 offset explicitly.

Comment: In regard to your question about custom time zones, if you just need a fixed offset zone, there is `DateTimeZone.ForOffset`.  If you need something more elaborate, you can create your own class that inherits from the abstract `DateTimeZone` base class.  If you have a lot of these, you might consider creating a custom provider by creating a class that implements the `IDateTimeZoneProvider` interface.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of unnecessary ceremony going on in your code sample, but the only potential bug I see is where you get the offset using `TimeSpan.FromHours(tzEastern.BaseUtcOffset.Hours)`.  That could be written shorter as just `tzEastern.BaseUtcOffset`, but still, that only works because it happens that the base offset is in effect at the time you provided.  Assuming that in your production code the input could be variable, then you should probably do this instead:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014, 11, 2, 2, 0, 0);
DateTimeOffset dateToTest = new DateTimeOffset(dt, tzEastern.GetUtcOffset(dt));
```

Do note though that if `dt` falls into an ambiguous local time range, `GetUtcOffset` will assume the *standard* time.  Likewise, if `dt` is invalid it will return the *standard* offset.  It would be reasonable to do something like this instead:

```
DateTime dt = // coming from your input

if (tzEastern.IsInvalidTime(dt))
{
   // Throw an exception to tell your user that the input is invalid.
}
else if (tzEastern.IsAmbiguousTime(dt))
{
   // Throw an exception to ask your user to pick from either EST (-5) or EDT (-4).
   // Use their choice of offset as a new input parameter.
}

DateTimeOffset dateToTest = new DateTimeOffset(dt, tzEastern.GetUtcOffset(dt));
```

I recommend that if the user is hanging around that you indeed prompt them.  However if that is not possible in your app, then you should simply decide what rules you want to follow.

Personally, I think it makes much more sense to favor the daylight time rather than the standard time.  (Think: if the time is invalid, then they didn't consider DST, so I'll advance the time for them; if the time is ambiguous then there are two possibilities and it likely makes sense to choose the first one.)  But that's just my opinion.  YMMV.

In regards to why your current code shows that `convertedTimeM` is ambiguous - at that point in your code you just have a `DateTime` with `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  Since there are two 1:00 points, then it is indeed ambiguous.  Michael Liu hit it on the nail - if you keep it as a `DateTimeOffset` then it's never ambiguous and you don't have to check.  One you have a `DateTimeOffset`, you can keep your output in a `DateTimeOffset`.  Also, that removes the need to convert to a UTC `DateTime` in the middle.

Also you should note that the Id for Arizona is "US Mountain Standard Time" - which is MST always, while "Mountain Standard Time" is for the rest of the Mountain time zone that alternates between MST and MDT.

Lastly, you might want to review the charts in [the DST tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).  That should make it clear that UTC to Local is deterministic while Local to UTC is not.

Comment: The date input is not prompted, but is rather the current time. I am sending the time to a device that can be in another time zone, and may or may not have DST (like Arizona). This test code is ginning up DateTime values for testing boundary conditions.

Comment: I made the change you suggested, using tzEastern.BaseUtcOffset.
When I get the dateToTest.UtcDateTime, I get a value that has no offset, and has DateTimeKind.Utc. This should be an unambiguous time converted to _any_ timezone, right? Why does ConvertTimeFromUtc() give me ambiguous answers? I'm still missing something.

Comment: UTC is unambiguous, yes, but the result from `ConvertTimeFromUtc` is a `DateTime` with `Unspecified` kind.  Those *can* be ambiguous.  The fact that it started out as UTC, and what zone you converted it to, are lost.  That's why it's better to use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`.

Comment: Also, if you use `.BaseUtcOffset`, you are specifically asking for the "standard time" offset - regardless of whether DST is applicable or in effect.

Comment: My intention was to convert two EST values, which is why I used .BaseUtcOffset.
I tried a version using DateTimeOffset and it still had the same problem. I expect that after conversion, it will be unspecified kind, because it's neither local nor UTC.

Comment: As crazy at it may sound, "Eastern Standard Time" as a `TimeZoneInfo.Id` does *not* mean EST.  It means "the time zone that alternates between EST and EDT".  So you can't assume that just because you used "Eastern Standard Time" in loading the time zone, that your conversion results will all be in EST.  The real world doesn't work like that anyway.