# Noda: Find out if in daylight saving

Tags: nodatime

How do I find out if my current local time is adjusted by Daylight Savings or not.
Basically the equivalent of `DateTime.Now.IsDaylightSavingTime()` in [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/)

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494174/jodatime-how-to-know-if-daylight-savings-is-on), but could not make the translation to Noda...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the System.TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime equivalent in NodaTime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211052/what-is-the-system-timezoneinfo-isdaylightsavingtime-equivalent-in-nodatime)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lasse's answer is correct, but it can be made simpler:

From v1.3 you can use [`ZonedDateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime`](https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/api/NodaTime.ZonedDateTime.html#NodaTime_ZonedDateTime_IsDaylightSavingTime):

```
var zone = ...;
var now = ..;
var daylight = now.InZone(zone).IsDaylightSavingTime();
```

And from v2.0 (unreleased at the time of writing) you can use [`ZonedClock`](https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/api/NodaTime.ZonedClock.html) to make the original conversion even simpler:

```
var now = zonedClock.GetCurrentZonedDateTime();
var daylight = now.IsDaylightSavingTime();
```

Comment: @MalcolmRowe: Ooh, thanks. I'd thought I'd only added it in 2.0 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var localTimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault();
var now = SystemClock.Instance.Now;
var interval = localTimeZone.GetZoneInterval(now);
// inspect interval.Savings
```

Comment: Thanks. This did it: var isDLS = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault().GetZoneInterval(SystemClock.Instance.Now).Savings.Ticks!=0